# Why extension method cannot exist in a nested class?

Tags: c#, nested

I have a static class having a static method which is an extension method, like this:

```
public static class N
{
    public static int Plus(this int i)
    {
        return i + 10;
    }
}
```

When I try to move this class into a class, to be a nested class, compiler reports error.

Why C# has this kind of limitation for extension method, what for? I don't see any danger that a nested class could contain extension method.

Thanks!

Comment: Beause they (Microsoft) wanted to make them easy to "discover"... They put a bunch of limitations just for this (for example the ext. method must be inside a static class... There is no reason for this other than "it is easier this way to discover it")

Comment: As good practice when asking questions, you should include the error you see in the body of the question.  You will get better help that way.